# CRUD enforcement does not allow access despite user privilegies

Tags: apex, permissions, custom-profile, crud

I've a custom object accessible for a custom profile cloned from Salesforce/ Standard user profile. The custom object was created using a System administrator user profile. I've granted access to this custom object for my custom profile by setting permission in Object Settings  :

[image]

But when testing CRUD from Apex, the custom object is still not accessible from the user custom profile :

```
CustomObject.sObjectType.getDescribe().isAccessible() // return false
```

Am i doing things well or is there something i've missed regarding user permissions to custom object?

Thanks for your help,

Comment: Did you use `System.runAs(concernedUser);` in the test class or just made the concerned user run the test class?

Comment: Yes  i'm using `System.runAs(concernedUser);` It's really strange as the custom profile and system administrator profile privilegies are same on this custom object...and i didn't set  any permission set for the user assigned to the custom profile...

Answer (score 1):

Finally found out what was happening. For anyone going around here, make sure to set your custom object as **Deployed** to be able to set permissions on your custom object properly.
[image]

> **What Is Deployment Status?**
>
> Deployment status lets you control who can access objects or platform
>   events. We recommend that you select In Development while you set up
>   your app or customization. That way, only admins (or users with the
>   Customize Application permission) can access the object or platform
>   event.
>
> When you’re ready to grant users access, change the status to
>   Deployed.
>
> Later, if you change the object or platform event, select In
>   Development again. Keep in mind that for custom or external objects,
>   users can’t see custom tabs, related lists, or reports while objects
>   are in development.